# Why did Valery Salov quit competitive chess?

Tags: grandmaster, famous-players

Why did Valery Salov stop playing in chess tournaments in the last 15 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this article](https://kevinspraggettonchess.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/what-ever-happened-to-valeri-salov/), it was because he was a pain in the ass and offended too many of chess' elite players. In fact, he seems unstable, not merely eccentric.

[And more here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rec.games.chess.misc/vM4HQ5d0YDk/ELZhs36uaRIJ). Looks like he decided he wasn't going to get along with people.

Comment: The latter article's claim that Salov was superior to K+K in the mid-90's is a stretch to say the least. The evidence given is that he won back-to-back tournaments in 1994-the same year as Karpov's 11/13 at Linares, a strong contender for the greatest tournament performance of all time.

Comment: Thank you for the articles, however it seems to me that he no longer plays competitive chess, which is actually different than "not getting invitations" or "not getting along with people". Perhaps he found a more remunerative job?

Comment: I now read Salov's recent public posts on Facebook regarding chess being completely manipulated by Masonic and Jewish leaders, Caruana's and Adams' perfect draw results in the 2015 London Chess Classic being a proof of that.